# Spring boot schedule task didn't wait to complete to shutdown

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have a schedule task with follow config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig {
@Value("${scheduled.task.pool.size}")
private int schedulerPoolSize;

@Value("${scheduled.task.thread.name.prefix}")
private String threadNamePrefix;

@Bean
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            this.getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor().setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
            super.destroy();
        }
    };

    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(schedulerPoolSize);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix(threadNamePrefix);               
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(20);
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Here is my task

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${scheduled.task.job1.fixed.delay}") 
public void scheduleTaskJob1() {
    logger.info("Fixed delay task called every 3 seconds after latest finished Execution Time - {}",
            dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
    String HttpErrorCode = "xxx";
    try {
            //10s taken to complete
        HttpErrorCode = mappingErrorService.getHttpErrorCode();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Ran into an error {}", ex);
    }

    logger.info("Current Thread : {} " + HttpErrorCode, Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

I was test many time but when stop my app, it alway show Ran into an error... and my task didn't complete succesfully.
it's seem setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown and setAwaitTerminationSeconds do not work.

I also try with

```
spring.quartz.wait-for-jobs-to-complete-on-shutdown=true
```

but no luck. My task alway fall into exception and didn't not get result

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck in the same problem. Were you able to solve the problem?